# Any way to use objects in gorm WHERE ... IN queries?

Tags: postgresql, go, go-gorm

Say, I want to run a query `SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE field IN ("a", "b")`.

The only way I found is `db.Where("field in ?", []string{"a", "b"}).Find(...)` but it has an issue - if I use case sensitive column names in Postgres, I have to decorate them with double quotes:

```
db.Where("\"Field\" in ?", []string{"a", "b"}).Find(...)
```

which is error prone, easy to forget adding `\"` to the field name string.

When you use objects in gorm queries, gorm takes case of adding those double quotes when needed:

```
db.Where(&User{Name: "John"}).Find(&users)
```

It will generate a query, decorating "Name" with double quotes for a Postgres query if the field is mixed case. But I can't find how to use objects with "WHERE .. IN" query instead of hardcoding field names in `db.Where("\"FieldName\" IN ?"...)`

Comment: Hi, @Andrey Did you find the solution later? I have the same requirement too.